# yuicompressor maven is not working

Tags: maven, pom.xml, minify, yui-compressor

I am working in Spring boot web application with maven build. I want to compress all js & css files. I have chosen YUI compression. When I build my application yui compression not happened. I am getting following message for all js & css files.

**[INFO] nothing to do, **css\base.css is younger than original, use 'force' option or clean your target**

What I am missing ?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
      <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!--   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
            my dependencies
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>true</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>compress</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>        
                    <configuration>
                      <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin> 
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Project structure : [image]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot but it still not clear where are CSS files? And do you see them somewhere inside of `target` directory? Also a full message from the plugin could be helpful.

Comment: Inside */src/main/resources/public folder i have both js & css files. After build is done I can see those js & css files in target folder. But those files were not compressed.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin Thank you. Updated answer working fine.

Comment: This case may have solution but the plugin version 1.5.1 has a bug because it cannot be configured for some simple cases. Say we want to configure webappDirectory and sourceDirectory.

If sourceDirectory is configured different from the default then the plugin executes compression twice once with the configured value and then with the default value which defeats the purpose of sourceDirectory configuration.

I haven't been able to compress from a directory that had to have changes made before compression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an error and works as expected. The plugin creates a minified version of the resource only when it's minified version doesn't exist or when source file has been changed. When plugin found that minified version was created later than source file, it doesn't do minification and assumes that nothing to be done.

As you can see, message suggests you to use `force` option (in this case, minified version will be always generated but it will be slower) or clean the target (execute `mvn clean` to remove all generated files so they will be generated again).

---

**UPDATED:**

I was able to reproduce the issue. It happens because yuicompressor-maven-plugin is being executed after maven-resource-plugin. The former was copied all the files from `src/main/resources` to the `target` directory and when yuicompressor was being executed, it found that the files already here (non-minified of course) and show this message.

To fix this, first, we need to configure resource plugin to exclude resources:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/public</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.js</exclude>
                <exclude>*/*.js</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

But it didn't solve it because after that I found that yuicompressor doesn't process these files. This is because the plugin was looking in the wrong directory and we have to configure it also:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/public</sourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: So how can I compress my js files ?

Comment: After build my files were not compressed.

Comment: Could you provide an example. Where are source files located? Where minified resources are placed? Also providing output of `ls -l` on these directories would be useful.

Comment: Updated my question. Added a screenshot of my project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dmaven.clean.failOnError=false` to mvn command.
example: `mvn clean -Dmaven.clean.failOnError=false`

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding `Force` option I resolved this issue:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>

                <force>true</force>

                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/static</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
               
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```